# how to export 3D avatar in fbx format on django-website

Tags: python, django

is there any piece of code to export my .fbx 3D avatar on the django-based website? i have gone through WebGl, three.js but can't solve the issue. thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you clarify what is the "django-based website" and how you want to export? From .fbx to/from another format?

Comment: website is being developed on python using web framework django. and i want to export my 3d model on that website which is an avatar made in unity in .fbx format.